# Can this be done a more efficient way (currently using puppeteer)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, puppeteer

so I am running a Puppeteer project and this is what I am doing:

- Going to a chat server
- parsing  proxy data
- parsing useragent
- parsing authentication cookie data ( to be logged in)
- replaying it every 60 seconds to show a user as logged in to a chat room

I am doing this with puppeteer and running 200 headless chrome instances.

Is there a better way of doing this instead of puppeteer as this is a crazy amount of ram on google cloud VM.

Meaning is the a less resource intensive way of going to a url parsing cookies and proxy information and replaying that info every 60 seconds for 200 unique session/instances (multilogin authentication cookies).Maybe http GET?

As I feel there is a faster more simple way of doing this but as an intermediate nodejs user, I am at a cross roads.

have tried axios but have not gotten that working. any help as I feel doing this with http get would make this much faster and less resource intennsive. Maybe using Request for node js would work?

Comment: how long do they take to run? If say, 5 seconds, then it seems you could recycle 1/12th as many boxes to keep up with 200/min.

Comment: Currently I run 10 headless chrome isntances every 60 seconds or else it crashes due to server overload.
Im sending 200 unique users to a chatroom using the cookie data. would using a http request get the job done better than puppeteer?
I need all 200 to be in the chatroom at a time, i refresh every 60 seconds due to how the chat works or else users wont be in chat as the chat is based on the exact time.

Comment: the http request mechanisms in browser (and headless ones) don't lend themselves to swapping out cookies like that. you _could_ likely get a LOT better efficiency with _curl_ or something like that, where you track the cookies with something like redis and swap them out as you round-robin the curls. It will be a bit more work to get up and running than fake browsers, but could very well be worth it for your project. It makes little sense (efficiency-wise) to fire up a css parser and decode jpegs (and tons of other wasted work that a browser does) just to make little more than a network ping

Comment: interesting, all the cookies I have saved in text and parse to json as I use a script to save auth cookies once logged in. Curl is the best method? Cant do this in node with request or another module?

Comment: i use curl more in the verb sense than the noun sense. to be sure, even a balnk node instance uses a lot of resources that a curl instance would not, but both are minuscule compared to browsers. Sounds like you might be able to accomplish the same thing as the headless without too much extra work using node tools

Comment: thanks
I am not trying to swap cookies however
trying to make 200 different requests with 200 different cookies(saved in txt format)  to the same address then at a set interval i refresh the page. I will do soem looking inot that.

Comment: This sounds a bit like a mild load test. You could use JMeter

Comment: ill have a look at it.thanks, its essentially a authenticated load test